# Dax Cumulative Sum of Select Rows

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a measure that calculates the cumulative amount of a column for rows with a date field earlier than the date field value in a row. It also must ignore some rows depending on the value in a type field. In this example I only want to include records where the Type field is in {1,4}. You can see in the table I provided what the results should. [example of cumulative calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx37u.png)

[Actual data screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Sp5b.png)

This is the DAX expression I tried, but the results keep grouping together the cumulative amounts based on the Type. Or in other words it is only showing the sum for the corresponding type in that row.

`VAR varDate = SELECTEDVALUE(Table[Date])

RETURN
CALCULATE(
round(SUM(Table[Amount]),2),
Table[Date] <= varDate &&
Table[Type] in {1,4}
) `

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this as a calculated column, then you will need to use FILTER to get the whole table

```
Cumulative = 
  var d = [Date]
  var r = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Amount]), FILTER('Table', 'Table'[Date] <= d && 'Table'[Type] IN {1, 4 }))
  RETURN ROUND(r, 2)
```

I tried your formula as a measure and it seemed to work correctly. Could you share a screen shot of the issue if this is the case.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I edited my post to include an actual screenshot of the results. It looks like for a row with type 1 only sums type 1 and rows with type 4 only sum rows with type 4.

Comment: Your Transaction Date column doesn't seem to be of Date data type (looks like it is a string). Can you confirm it is indeed a Date column? Could you also add the "Type" column in your screen snip (missing). Finally, is this a calculated column or measure?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by adding ALL(Table) in the CALCULATE function. This removes the context filters for a row allowing the summation to bring in the rows with Type values that do not equal the row's Type value.

```
VAR varDate = SELECTEDVALUE(Table[Date])

RETURN CALCULATE(round(SUM(Table[Amount]),2), ALL(Table), Table[Date] <= varDate && Table[Type] in {1,4})
```